# Cannot run api calls after setting the wcf in IIS7

Tags: wcf

I have set up my IIS Locally and running fine. After that I have setup in a windows server and tried to access my urls.

```
http://localhost:7000/MyHoome.svc
```

The above service url works but when I try to access a URI

```
http://localhost:7000/MyHoome.svc/winterhome/getlocks/pass/winter
```

it gives me an error screen, but in my local IIS it works fine. I Dont have many experience in WCF. Um very happy if someone can give me a solution

ERROR MESSAGE

> Error Summary
>       HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>       The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily     unavailable.

Comment: Show your REST service config and contracts.

Comment: You say "but in my local IIS it works fine" - with your second URI, is that on a different machine?  If it is, then `localhost` won't work.  You'll need to specify the name of the machine (if it's on the network) or the domain the other server is hosting the service one.